# Visual Studio 2010 Attaching to Python Process

Tags: python, visual-studio, dll, symbols

I'm using VS 2010 to attach to a Python script that is calling a DLL via ctypes.

I can attach to the process and under the "Modules" view I can see the DLL and it's associated PDB. The paths lead right to the solutions output folder which happens to be ".../Debug/bin". I'm running the script from this same folder.

When I try to set a breakpoint I get "No executable code is associated with this line."

As best as I can tell the DLL is built in a debug configuration rather than a release (under Properties/C-C++/Optimization optimization is disabled (/Od). However, in the "Modules" view the "Optimized" column displays "Yes".

Thanks,

Kenny

Comment: With the help of a coworker I found that a good solution is to start with the DLL project then in the project debug settings set "Python.exe" as the command, my script as an argument to the command, and no to "attach", and it works as expected. This works for my immediate needs but it's still unclear why I cannot set breakpoints when attaching to python.exe when the script was externally launched.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using VS 2010, install the [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) extension that was released a few months ago. It is awesome.

- Supports CPython and IronPython
- Python editor with advanced member and signature intellisense
- Code navigation, goto definition, and object browser
- **Local and remote debugging**

With this installed you should be able to debug your script directly.

http://pytools.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is a nice addition but it didn't help me with this symbols issue. Still I'm very happy to see these kinds of tools for Python.